# nginx returns 404 instead of farwarding the request to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am using nginx and Pushion passenger. If I request this resource https://www.chinadialogue.net/article/show/single/ch/3982-Moving-past-Mexico I get a 404 from nginx instead of hitting Rails. I checked the logs. Rails is using SLUGs so anything after 3982 (article ID) still returns 3982, try:

https://www.chinadialogue.net/article/show/single/ch/3982-
https://www.chinadialogue.net/article/show/single/ch/3982-Moving-past-Mexico1

They wall works. I do not have any 'rewrite' I restarted nginx but nothing. I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to find out if the request is indeed not reaching Rails or if something is going wrong with your slug implementation.

Look in your rails log (log/production.log) and hit the URL that returns the 404.

Do you see the request come in? Or does nothing show up at all.

If nothing shows up you'll know that you have to investigate your nginx configuration further.

If something does show up, and it looks like it's going to the right controller and the right action then you'll have a clue of where to investigate further in your rails app.

It could also be that the routes in your rails app have a certain constraint (ending in integer perhaps?)

Without more information about your setup, getting a definitive answer is not possible.

Comment: Hi, as I said I checked both logs, Rails and nginx). The site has hundreds of articles and SLUG does not have any problems, plus the request is not reaching the Rails app anyway. I cannot post the config here, but I disable most of the directive in nginx configuration without luck.

Comment: I was messing around a bit and was able to recreate the 404 by adding Mexico to other slugs. Figured it can't be "Mexico" that triggers it. After more fiddling, looks like ending in "ico" is the problem. Perhaps a nginx directive for assets is causing this? In any case search for "ico" in your nginx conf

Comment: Yup probably an un escaped  dot in the regex? Problem also occurs when ending in png https://www.chinadialogue.net/article/show/single/ch/3982-Moving-past-Mexico-png

Comment: this is a duplication of this http://serverfault.com/questions/213800/nginx-returning-404-error-on-a-valid-url. I realised that I was changing the files in the wrong nginx directory, there are two old nginx versions. So yes it was a rewrite issue but the favicon.ico really put me in the right direction: